# list view not display on some devices

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that I'm populating with an ArrayAdapter.Its work fine most of devices.But i have one karbonn(320x480) device which unable to display list.My application contain many listview they display properly on karbonn.

My .xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e6f0f5"
    tools:context=".Save_educationActivity" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#4791FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/xibtn_save_education"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#4791FF"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_save" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/xibtn_back_to_education"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#4791FF"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_back" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/Education_title" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" Course Name"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/xedt_course"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/xedt_course"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Joining Date"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lvdate"
        android:text="Leave Date"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/jdate"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Joining Date"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lvdate"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Leaving Date"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jdate"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_education_desc"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/date_stroke"
            android:text="Add Description"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_edu_desc"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/date_stroke"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1">


           <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_eductndesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have very buggy layout. I will show you tour mistakes:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#4791FF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" > // there is no such attribute in relative layout


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/xibtn_save_education"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#4791FF"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_save" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/xibtn_back_to_education"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#4791FF"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_back" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text="@string/Education_title" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" // which size of scroll view you expected here? It will grow with their content and never have scroll.
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

    <RelativeLayout // you don't need to have relative layout here.
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Course Name"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/xedt_course"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/xedt_course"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Joining Date"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lvdate"
    android:text="Leave Date"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/jdate"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Joining Date"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lvdate"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Leaving Date"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/jdate"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_education_desc"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/date_stroke"
        android:text="Add Description"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_edu_desc"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/date_stroke"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  // which height you expect here? It will have height the same as parent, but draws somewhere at the bottom. It will draw a large part of view outside of screen.
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1">


       <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lst_eductndesc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think you need reformat your layout at all. If you will show image what you want to achieve and explain it's behavior, I will help to write more effeicient and clean xml.

You can make your layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e6f0f5"
    tools:context=".Save_educationActivity" 
     android:orientation="vertical">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#4791FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" > // there is no such attribute in relative layout


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/xibtn_save_education"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#4791FF"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_save" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/xibtn_back_to_education"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#4791FF"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_back" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/Education_title" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" // you must declare your height exactly here
>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" Course Name"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


    </ScrollView>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/xedt_course"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/xedt_course"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout layout_width="match_parent"
layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout layout_width="0dp"
laout_weight="1"
layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Joining Date"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/jdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Joining Date"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout layout_width="0dp"
laout_weight="1"
layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Leave Date"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lvdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Leaving Date"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_education_desc"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/date_stroke"
            android:text="Add Description"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_edu_desc"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/date_stroke"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

           <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_eductndesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Amol007 you can post link to image on other server.

Comment: It properly worked. where is my mistake i can't understand its .xml file problem or .java file?

Comment: You design is scary. First of all, your top bar must be actual actionbar. You don't need to do it your self. Back button on screen is bad. Android always has hardware back button. Save button is scary on mobile device. Adding listView at bottom of your layout is not usable on small devices. Therefore I'll post xml for you.

Comment: Also, I added comments what you are doing wrong to your code

Comment: thnx for your valuable time . still not working may be its .java file problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using RelativeLayouts and aligning your views beneath one another, it's likely that the layout is extending beyond the bottom of the screen.

I encourage you to use a different combination of ViewGroups, for instance using a vertically oriented LinearLayout inside a ScrollView.

Comment: But its work fine another phone. I have another 320x480 device there works this code.

Comment: Perhaps the screen density of the "karbonn" is higher. This is all speculation, as I don't know what you mean with "doesn't work".